# I am unable to understand the loop

Tags: javascript

I am unable to understand what is happening although they are the same code. The problem is that (while loop) starts from 1 and ends at 100 but (for loop) starts from 0 and ends to 99. Please explain great detail so that I can understand the loop properly.

```
let num = 0;

while (num < 100){
    num += 1;
    console.log(num);
}



for(let i = 0; i < 100; i++){
    console.log(i);
}
```

Comment: There are literally tons of answers available on that if you'd simply google ```while```  vs ```for``` loop.

Comment: `num` and `i` are incremented in different places.

Comment: they are the same code

Answer (score 0):

```
let num = 0;

while (num < 100){
    console.log(num);
    num += 1;  
}



for(let i = 0; i < 100; i++){
    console.log(i);
}
```

The while loop and for loop will get the same result

Because the variable num increment after printing log like variable i increment after printing log

Comment: yes they are the same result but while starts from number 1 to 100 although for loop starts from number 0 to 99. This is the thing I want to know

Comment: let num = 0;

while (num < 100){
    num += 1;
    console.log(num);
}

Comment: Yes this `let num = 0; while (num < 100){ num += 1; console.log(num); } ` will get 1 to 99

Comment: But this `let num = 0; while (num < 100){ console.log(num); num += 1;  } ` 
will get 0 to 99

Comment: this `let num = 0; while (num <= 100){
    console.log(num);
    num += 1;  
}` will get 0 to 100